# TensorFlow: removing/adding Variable to computational graph

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow, but can't find any conclusive documentation on this. Is it possible to dynamically remove variables from an initialized session? Or add variables similarly? Would this require recompiling/initialising the computational graph every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add individual variables to the session using

```
init_new_vars_op = tf.initialize_variables([v_6, v_7, v_8])
sess.run(init_new_vars_op)
```

Doesn't require recompiling the graph.

Don't know about removing variables, I haven't found anything either, anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: thanks, but how would these variables tie into a graph? like `y=sum(w*x for w in ws)` and now you wish to add some weights to the list `ws`, your function would initialise them, but not add them to the function `y` right?

Comment: If you actually want to change the size of ws then unfortunately I think you have no option but to create a new graph. If you simply want to change the values for ws then the best option is a placeholder variable.

Comment: so essentially tensorflow is no different from Theano? Just some quicker graph compile time and no advanced indexing?

Comment: There are a few more differences, but they are very similar.

Comment: thanks a bunch for your time with this PS: removing variables can be simply done by removing them from the python structure and recompiling the graph, whether that garbage collects i dont know